# SwiftUI View does not update

Tags: swiftui

The content of `CardView` inside the `ForEach` of `CardNavigatorView` is correctly updated thanks to an async download task (inside `CardView`) that downloads an image, and the `Image()` is displayed correctly, but I detected that the frame around `CardView` in `CardNavigatorView` is not updated accordingly causing the `Text("test")` to appear in the middle of the `CardView` image, instead of being pushed down by the `CardView` frame if it was updated correctly, to encircle the image. The `border(Color.red, width:2)` helped me to conclude this as it appears as if it was empty. 
Any suggestion please ?

```
struct CardNavigatorView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: CardNavigatorViewModel
    @State private var offset: CGFloat = 0
    let spacing: CGFloat = 10

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            return ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: true) {
                HStack(spacing: self.spacing) {
                    ForEach(self.model.cardSource.cards, id:\.hashString) { card in
                        CardView(card: card)
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width).border(Color.red, width: 2)
                    }
                }
            }
            .content.offset(x: self.offset)
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, alignment: .leading)
        }
        Text("Test")
    }
}
```

CardView is declared as following

```
struct CardView: View {
    @ObservedObject var card: Card
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
                    ImageViewContainer(imageUrl: self.card.imagesURL[0])
                        .frame(width:geometry.size.width)
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .clipped()
                    NameView(name: self.card.name)
                        .frame(width:geometry.size.width)
                    Button(action:{
                        self.userData.toggleFav(card:self.card)
                    }) {
                        ZStack{                        Image("fav_icon").renderingMode(Image.TemplateRenderingMode?.init(Image.TemplateRenderingMode.original))
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode:.fit)
                            .frame(width:25).opacity(self.card.isFav ? 1 : 0).offset(x:-10, y:10)
                            Image("not_fav_icon").renderingMode(Image.TemplateRenderingMode?.init(Image.TemplateRenderingMode.original))
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode:.fit)
                                .frame(width:25).opacity(self.card.isFav ? 0 : 1).offset(x:-10, y:10)
                        }
                    }
                }.border(Color.green, width: 3)

                Text("\(self.card.description)")
                Text("Note : \(self.card.ratingString)")

            }.onAppear{self.userData.setUserSettingsTo(card: self.card)}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I now can say that this is not the async task that cause the issue. I tested with an image from my library and still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found. For people wondering what was wrong:
I guess that the `GeometryReader` in `CardView` gets the size of the `ScrollView` of the parent `CardNavigatorView`, which is in turn considered as empty. Since `GeometryReader` closures allows to expand outside of its border, I got the effect I tried to explain.
The tip is to provide a `frame(width:geometry.size.width)` modifier to the CardView instance! (to be tuned up to your need)